# SSRS - Hide rectangle based on a flag present in separate dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a SSRS report, where a rectangle box contains several tables and charts based on one dataset (say ds_1), however the visibility of that the rectangle box is dependent on one specific flag (say field = visibility_flag) in other dataset (ds_2 containing columns 'field' and 'value').
Case1: field = visibility_flag AND value = 'Y'
Expected o/p: the output report will have the rectangle box
Case2: field = visibility_flag AND value = 'N'
OR
Case3: flag is not present at all
Expected o/p: For both case 2 and 3, the rectangle box will be hidden in the report. How do I achieve this?

I tried using function First() and Last() in "Hidden" expression but it did not work as this flag may not always be the first/last value present in ds_2

Comment: `1.` You'll probably need to show a sample of data from both datasets and `2.` explain the relationship between them. `3.` If the flag is not in each record, how do know which record to use or is the presence of the flag anywhere in dataset2 actually what you are looking for ?  `4.` show the expression you have tried so far even if it does not work, it will still help people understand what you are trying to do. `5.` **Edit** your question to include as much info as you can, don't answer these questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a couple of IIF statements to check the other dataset to determine if it has the Veisibility Field and the Value is set to Y.

```
=IIF(
    MAX(
        IIF(Fields.FIELD.Value = "visibility_flag" AND Fields.VALUE.Value = "Y", 1, 0)
        , "ds_2")
    = 1, False, True)
```

The inner IIF with the MAX will search the ds_2 dataset for the Visibility Flag and if the value is Y then return 1. The outer if will check the value and set the results to True or False depending on the result.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below link which is having solution for similar problem mentioned in the question.
[ssrs-how-to-show-multiple-reports-in](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2018/08/ssrs-how-to-show-multiple-reports-in.html)

Thanks,
BI_Help